# Am I using static in the right way?

Tags: c#, xna, static-variables

I'm writing an XNA engine and I am storing all of the models in a `List`.  In order to be able to use this throughout the engine, I've made this a `public static List<Model>` so I can access it from any new classes that I develop.  It certainly makes obtaining the list of models really easy to get too, but is this the right usage?  Or would I be better off actually passing a variable through in a method declaration?

Comment: are you using any kind of threading? If so, then you truly whant to avoid a static List.

Comment: @Marthin: No threading is being used.

Comment: Then from my experiance I think you could go ahead with your static list as long as you know that its a fairly small project. However, if you think this might grow then I would suggest going with a factory. Factories are ofcourse not optimal for all these kinds of implementations but for me, they useally make the implamentation a bit easier and gets very handy. Finaly a Tip: Read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. Best practise for all programmers Java, .NET and others =) GL!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OOP it's generally advisable to avoid using static methods and properties, unless you have a very good reason to do so. One of the reasons for that is that in the future you may want to have two or more instances of this list for some reason, and then you'll be stuck with static calls.

Static methods and properties are too rigid. As [Stevey](http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid) states it:

> Static methods are as flexible as
>   granite. Every time you use one,
>   you're casting part of your program in
>   concrete. Just make sure you don't
>   have your foot jammed in there as
>   you're watching it harden. Someday you
>   will be amazed that, by gosh, you
>   really DO need another implementation
>   of that dang PrintSpooler class, and
>   it should have been an interface, a
>   factory, and a set of implementation
>   classes. D'oh!

Answer (score 5):

For game development I advocate "Doing The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work". That includes using global variables (`public static` in C#), if that is an easy solution. You can always turn it into something more formal later. The "find all references" tool in Visual Studio makes this really easy.

*That being said*, there are very few cases where a global variable is actually the "correct" way to do something. So if you are going to use it, you should be *aware of* and *understand* the correct solution. So you can make the best tradeoff between "being lazy" and "writing good code".

**If you are going to make something global, you need to fully understand *why* you are doing so.**

In this particular case, it sounds like you're trying to trying to get at content. You should be aware that `ContentManager` will automatically return the *same* content object if you ask for it multiple times. So rather than loading models into a global list, consider making your `Game` class's built-in `ContentManager` available via  a `public static` property on your `Game` class.

Or, better still, there's a method that I prefer, that I think is a bit better: [I explain it in the answer to another question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/when-should-a-bullet-texture-be-loaded-in-xna/9310#9310). Basically you make the content references `private static` in the classes that use them and pass the `ConentManager` into `public static LoadContent` functions. This compartmentalises your use of static to individual classes, rather than using a global that is accessed from all over your program (which would be difficult to extricate later). It also correctly handles loading content at the *correct time*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using static as much as possible, over time you'll just end up with [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

If you pass it in the constructor you're eliminating an unnecessary dependency, [low coupling is good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). The fewer dependencies there are, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement a Singleon object which encapsulates the model list.
Have a look at the [MSDN singleton implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: Singletons have their own disadvantages, and actually they are not very different from objects having static methods. Here is one post about it: http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid Generally it's better to just create an object and pass it as a parameter to whoever needs to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of balance and trade-offs.

Of course, OOP purists will say that avoid such global variables at all costs, since it breaks code compartmentization by introducing something that goes "out of the box" for any module, and thus making it hard to maintain, change, debug etc.

However, my personal experience has been that it should be avoided only if you are part of a very large enterprise solutions team, maintaining a very large enterprise-class application.

For others cases, encapsulating globally-accessible data into a "global" object (or a static object, same thing) simplifies OOP coding to a great extent.

You may get the middle-ground by writing a global GetModels() function that returns the list of models.  Or use DI to automatically inject the list of models.

Comment: Small projects can later grow larger. And even the smallest projects should be testable. Statics are enemy of unit testing.

Comment: @František Žiačik, good point!  +1  That's why I mention that he may need to have a GetModels() function so that you can inject a dummy in unit tests...

Comment: @František Žiačik, however, in games development, there is usually a large amount of global data (e.g. board data, terrain data, players data etc) to sync among code streams.  Actually, global data usually far exceeds non-global data.  So there must be some form of a balance.